# How to delete an existing row of a worksheet in Excel by using XLSX in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx, sheetjs

How to delete an existing row of a worksheet of a workbook in Excel by using the XLSX from SheetJS in Node.js?

*The code so far:*

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

// read the file
workBook = xlsx.readFile("todo-list.xlsx", {cellDates:true});

// read the worksheet
const shoppingList = workBook.Sheets["Do-Shopping"];

// delete a specific row
........ [here I dont know even how to start]

// write the data to the Excel file
xlsx.writeFile(workBook, 'todo-list.xlsx');
```

*Desired results:*

BEFORE:
[image: before]
AFTER:
[image: after]

But the deleted row could be anyone, like the first one or the third one, not necessary the last one.

I tried searching on the official docs and stack, but I have not found an answer yet. :( and I am new to Node js

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found on the [Github's site](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/352#issuecomment-230440553), works very well on any row:

```
// delete a specific row
function ec(r, c){
    return xlsx.utils.encode_cell({r:r,c:c});
}
function delete_row(ws, row_index){
    var variable = xlsx.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"])
    for(var R = row_index; R < variable.e.r; ++R){
        for(var C = variable.s.c; C <= variable.e.c; ++C){
            ws[ec(R,C)] = ws[ec(R+1,C)];
        }
    }
    variable.e.r--
    ws['!ref'] = xlsx.utils.encode_range(variable.s, variable.e);
}
delete_row(shoppingList, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I tried this is not working.Please have a look.
const XLSX = require('xlsx')
var filename = './customer_data.xlsx'
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename)
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]

function ec(r, c) {
    return XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: r, c: c });
}
function delete_row(ws, row_index) {
    var variable = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"])
    console.log(variable);
    for (var R = row_index; R < variable.e.r; ++R) {
        for (var C = variable.s.c; C <= variable.e.c; ++C) {
            console.log(C);
            ws[ec(R, C)] = ws[ec(R + 1, C)];
        }
    }
    variable.e.r--
    ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(variable.s, variable.e);
}
var result = delete_row(worksheet, 2);
console.log(result);
```